# Get all combination of a nested object with arbitrary levels

Tags: javascript, recursion, depth-first-search

I have a JSON data which can be an object/array of recursively nested object or array. The value of an array can not be null, but an value in a object can be null. I would like to return all combination of these keys and values through depth first search.

For example:

```
var data = {
  "title": {
     "original": "Hitchhiker",
     "more": ["HGTTG"],
     "link": null
  },
  "date": ["20150101", "20160101"]
}
```

The data's length and depth is arbitrary, and the combination result I want is something like this:

```
["title-original-Hitchhiker", "title-more-HTTG", "title-link", "date-20150101", "date-20160101"]
```

What I came up with is recursive:

```
function nestedObjectToArray(obj) {
  if (typeof(obj) != "object"){
    return [obj];
  }
  var result = [];
  if (obj.constructor == Array){
    for (var i = 0; i <obj.length; i++){
      if (obj[i]){
        var temp = nestedObjectToArray(obj[i]);
        for (var j = 0; j < temp.length; j++){
          result.push(temp[j]);
        }
      }
    }
  } else {
    for (var i in obj){
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        if (obj[i] == null){
          result.push(i);
        } else {
          var temp = nestedObjectToArray(obj[i]);
          for (var j = 0; j < temp.length; j++){
            result.push(i+"-"+temp[j]);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Would you have a better/more elegant solution then this chunk of conditions, loops and recursion? I can use any lib if it's more convenient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is clean and works fine.
The only little point I've noticed is that you didn't follow this rule:

- instead of (for instance) `for (var i = 0; i <obj.length; i++)`
- you should write `for (var i = 0, n = obj.length; i < n; i++)`, so the `obj.length` is evaluated only once rather than for each iteration

That's said, it may be possible that it doesn't matter any longer in modern browsers, due to optimizers.

Beyond that, I was interested by your challenge to find "a better/more elegant solution".

Then I found one that uses reduced code, and probably works faster:

```js
var data = {
  "title": {
     "original": "Hitchhiker",
     "more": ["HGTTG"],
     "link": null
  },
  "date": ["20150101", "20160101"]
}

function nestedObjectToArray(obj, prefix) {
  prefix = prefix ? prefix : '';
  var result = [], isArray = Array.isArray(obj), value, nextPrefix;
  obj = typeof obj == 'object' ? obj : JSON.parse('{"' + obj + '": null}');
  for (var key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      value = obj[key];
      nextPrefix = prefix + (isArray ? '' : (key + '-'));
      result = result.concat(
        value === null ? (prefix + key) : nestedObjectToArray(value, nextPrefix)
      );
    }
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(nestedObjectToArray(data));
```

The main points of interest are:

- The function gets a second argument `prefix` which is recursively transmitted, growing as depth increases: this allows to always add the *complete* prefix at each level, instead of having to re-process the complete result returned to prepend each item with the key of the ancestor level.
- There is a unique loop to process arrays and objects: since the only difference is the absence/presence of a key, the test (is array ?) is made at this precise point, *inside* the generation for the current item:
  `nextPrefix = prefix + (isArray ? '' : (key + '-'));`.
- More over, also a final "leaf" is not processed separately, like:
  `if (typeof(obj) != "object") {return [obj];}` in your version;
  instead, the leaf is transformed into an object:
  `obj = typeof obj == 'object' ? obj : JSON.parse('{"' + obj + '": null}');`
  so it can be processed in the loop, where it falls into the (already planned by design, following your initial needs) case of `null` value: the trick is that the value became a key.